# Use pivotal cloud foundry redis and rabbitmq service using as vcap service in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, redis, rabbitmq, spring-jms, cloud-foundry

I am able to use REDIS and RABBITMQ services which is on pivotal.While binding services I am able to get the Credentials and using that credentials in my application.properties for spring boot project.

But this configuration that I am using is hard-coded in application.Properties
To Make this configuration dynamically I came to know that we can use vcap services provided by pivotal.

So want to use run-time credentials for redis and rabbimq.

My Code is below for reference.

application.propeties

```
rabbitmq.host=hostname
rabbitmq.virtual-host=vhostanme
rabbitmq.username=username
rabbitmq.password=password
rabbit.mainqueue=abhi
rabbit.errorqueue=abc
redis.host=redishostname
redis.port=port
redis.password=password
```

My Config class:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Config {


    static String rabbitMqHost;
    static String rabbitMqVHost;
    static String rabbitMqUsername;
    static String rabbitMqPassword;
    static String rabbitMqMainQueue;
    static String rabbitMqErrorQueue;
    static String redisHost;
    static int redisPort;
    static String redisPassword;


    Config() {
    }


    public static String getRedisHost() {
        return redisHost;
    }

    public static void setRedisHost(String redisHost) {
        Config.redisHost = redisHost;
    }

    public static int getRedisPort() {
        return redisPort;
    }

    public static void setRedisPort(int redisPort) {
        Config.redisPort = redisPort;
    }

    public static String getRedisPassword() {
        return redisPassword;
    }

    public static void setRedisPassword(String redisPassword) {
        Config.redisPassword = redisPassword;
    }

    public static String getRabbitMqMainQueue() {
        return rabbitMqMainQueue;
    }

    public static void setRabbitMqMainQueue(String rabbitMqMainQueue) {
        Config.rabbitMqMainQueue = rabbitMqMainQueue;
    }

    public static String getRabbitMqErrorQueue() {
        return rabbitMqErrorQueue;
    }

    public static void setRabbitMqErrorQueue(String rabbitMqErrorQueue) {
        Config.rabbitMqErrorQueue = rabbitMqErrorQueue;
    }

    public static String getRabbitMqHost() {
        return rabbitMqHost;
    }

    public static void setRabbitMqHost(String rabbitMqHost) {
        Config.rabbitMqHost = rabbitMqHost;
    }

    public static String getRabbitMqVHost() {
        return rabbitMqVHost;
    }

    public static void setRabbitMqVHost(String rabbitMqVHost) {
        Config.rabbitMqVHost = rabbitMqVHost;
    }

    public static String getRabbitMqUsername() {
        return rabbitMqUsername;
    }

    public static void setRabbitMqUsername(String rabbitMqUsername) {
        Config.rabbitMqUsername = rabbitMqUsername;
    }

    public static String getRabbitMqPassword() {
        return rabbitMqPassword;
    }

    public static void setRabbitMqPassword(String rabbitMqPassword) {
        Config.rabbitMqPassword = rabbitMqPassword;
    }

    @Value("${rabbitmq.host}")
    public void setRabbitMqHosts(String url) {
        setRabbitMqHost(url);
    }

    @Value("${rabbitmq.virtual-host}")
    public void setRabbitMqVHosts(String url) {
        setRabbitMqVHost(url);
    }

    @Value("${rabbitmq.username}")
    public void setRabbitUsernames(String url) {
        setRabbitMqUsername(url);
    }

    @Value("${rabbitmq.password}")
    public void setRabbitPasswords(String url) {
        setRabbitMqPassword(url);
    }

    @Value("${rabbit.mainqueue}")
    public void setRabbitMainQueues(String url) {
        setRabbitMqMainQueue(url);
    }

    @Value("${rabbit.errorqueue}")
    public void setRabbitErrorQueues(String url) {
        setRabbitMqErrorQueue(url);
    }

    @Value("${redis.host}")
    public void setRedisHosts(String url) {
        setRedisHost(url);
    }

    @Value("${redis.port}")
    public void setRedisPorts(int url) {
        setRedisPort(url);
    }
    @Value("${redis.password}")
    public void setRedisPasswords(String url) {
        setRedisPassword(url);
    }
}
```

My MessagesConsumer class in which I am using that Conguration to take message from rabbitmq jms queue and save to redis:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.Session;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.es.consumer.config.Config;
import com.rabbitmq.jms.admin.RMQConnectionFactory;

import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisShardInfo;

@Component
public class MessagesConsumer {
    @Autowired
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessagesConsumer.class);

    Jedis jedis;

    JedisShardInfo shardInfo;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        shardInfo = new JedisShardInfo(Config.getRedisHost(), Config.getRedisPort());
        shardInfo.setPassword(Config.getRedisPassword());
        jedis = new Jedis(shardInfo);
        jedis.connect();
        jedis.select(2);

    }

    @Bean
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {

        RMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new RMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setUsername(Config.getRabbitMqUsername());
        connectionFactory.setPassword(Config.getRabbitMqPassword());
        connectionFactory.setVirtualHost(Config.getRabbitMqVHost());
        connectionFactory.setHost(Config.getRabbitMqHost());
        return connectionFactory;

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1)
    public void readQueueAndSaveData() {
// take message process it and save to redis as hmset

}}
```

Any Help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this.
1) Remove all the properties from application.properties, and write a configuration bean that will create RedisTemplate and RabbitTemplate beans for you. The factory properties required for these are to be obtained from the VCAP_SERVICES. On CF, the VCAP_SERVICES env variable, will have the services information that are binded to the app. When u push the app, with redis, rabbit service binded into your space, then their properties are available in VCAP_SERVICES. So just do `System.getEnv("VCAP_SERVICES")` in your code and then parse the json to get the service details to create the templates.

2) Remove the properties from application.properties, and use spring cloud connector. Spring cloud has a subproject called Spring cloud connectors that provide utilities to connect to various cloud services.

```
http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-spring-service-connector.html#_rabbitmq
```

Just you need to define a class that extends AbstractCloudConfig as below

```
class CloudConfig extends AbstractCloudConfig {
    @Bean
    public RabbitConnectionFactory rabbitFactory() {
        return connectionFactory().rabbitConnectionFactory("rabbit-servicename");
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisConnectionFactory redisFactory() {
        return connectionFactory().redisConnectionFactory("redis-servicename");
    }
}
```

The second approach is prefered if you are using Spring, as this needs very less coding and can be switched, to different cloud providers with no much effort.

Comment: can i get dependencies for   @Bean
    public RabbitConnectionFactory rabbitFactory() {
        return connectionFactory().rabbitConnectionFactory("rabbit-servicename");
    }

The dependencies i have tried for this is : 
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.8.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: but I want to save data in redis as hash using HMSET But I think redis template does not support hmset.

Comment: The dependencies to use. <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector</artifactId>
</dependency>     RedisTemplate may support HMSET. I am not sure and have not tried, but take a look at this link. http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/RedisHashCommands.html#hMSet-byte:A-java.util.Map-

Comment: the return type of `rabbitFactory` method should be `ConnectionFactory‌` (org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory), not RabbitConnectionFactory. Refer https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors/issues/220 for more details.